# CountUp to target number

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a countUp the number like this [Site](http://adamrudzki.com)  but I dont want the slide in effect, just the countUp to target number. Anyone know how to do that with jquery? Thanks

Comment: You really should try it first and ask a question if you get stuck.  Just asking us to code for you isn't very cool

Comment: I'm new to jquery, there're a lot of things to learn. I just try to learn what do the code does to run this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/3CyHY/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var div = 360 / 6;
    var radius = 150;
    var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
    var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(parentdiv.offsetWidth / 2);  //assumes parent is square
    var offsetToChildCenter = 20;
    var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
    {
        var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
        childdiv.className = 'div2';
        childdiv.id = 'div_'+i;
        childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
        var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
        childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
        childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
        parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
    }

     $('#div_1').countTo({
            from: 0,
            to: 10,
            speed: 3000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });

     $('#div_2').countTo({
            from: 0,
            to: 100,
            speed: 3000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
});
```

See full source in jsfiddle

Comment: Thank so much! This's very complicate script for me. Is there another way to make it simple. This is what I imagine:  fn.countUp = function(){  }); and then call the function like $('class or id').countUp(3000).

Comment: yes you can always. the complex part is to create that circles and square graphics. actual function is countTo so use that in whatever you like. basically countTo is counter function for any element.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/3CyHY/1/